# String.class loaded from which class loader?

Tags: java, classloader

```
package com.ajay.test;

public class ClassLoaderDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(String.class.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(ClassLoaderDemo.class.getClassLoader());
    }

}
```

**Output**:

```
null

sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
```

Why I am getting String.class.getClassLoader() as null?

Comment: There is a "bootstrap" classloader which loads some of the classes in base packages (and sometimes in other packages, on certain condition). Classes which are loaded by bootstrap loader don't report a class loader.

Comment: Read the Javadoc of method [`Class.getClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--). It is described there what the returned `null` means.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch got you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()):

> public ClassLoader getClassLoader()
>
> Returns the class loader for the class. Some implementations may use
> null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return
> null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap
> class loader.